# PowerShell Script to Remove Registry Item

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm trying to make a PowerShell script that checks a set registry key for a range of names that start the same. That part I have working fine. I also need this script to than remove those items from that registry and I am having trouble remembering how to pass the names of all items I find so that Remove-ItemProperty will work. This is what I have.

```
$Reg = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices'


Get-ItemProperty -Path $Reg | Select-Object IS* | ForEach-Object {$PSItem.Name} | Remove-ItemProperty -Path $Reg -Name $name
```

The message I get is that Name is null so I'm not storing the names correctly. They display correctly if I just run the first two pipes.

Comment: I know after powershell version 3 you can use $_ instead of $PSItem. Although, I doubt that this is the issue since powershell is normally pretty good about being backward compatible.

Comment: From what I was told it was the other way around but both work.

Comment: `Select-Object IS*` throws away all properties whose names do not start with `IS` - including the `Name` property

Comment: @IanCatapano If you want better visibility you can always assign the first two pipes to a variable and then loop through those with a Foreach. A bit more complicated, but it will allow you to see what's going on. I don't know your situation exactly, but I'd try removing the third pipe and inserting the fourth in the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Had to re-write a bit to make the property name stick.

`Get-Item -Path "$Reg" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | 
ForEach-Object {if ($_ -match "IS*"){Remove-ItemProperty -Path "$Reg" -Name "$_"}}`

Comment: Ah I knew I forgot something, thanks everyone for the help. Though it still isn't removing the items. At least there is no error messages so it should be close to working.

Comment: lol probably help if I used -ExpandProperty and not -ExcludeProperty

Comment: OK everything seems to be working except it doesn't seem to be finding anything with the if statement. I tried using -like and still not getting anything. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: OK so I got it to work, I was still trying to use $PSItem and that does not work for this. I guess one shouldn't trust everything you learn in classes you pay good money for. Again thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't get it to work with $psitem, use $_ instead --- it's the pipeline object, which is what you want anyways.